# Does a lvalue have a type?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, lvalue

In C11 standard

> 6.3.2.1  Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
>
> 1 An lvalue is  an  expression  (with  an  object  type  other  than
> void) that  potentially designates an object;) if an lvalue does
> not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior  is
> undeﬁned. When  an  object  is  said  to  have  a  particular  type,
> the  type  is speciﬁed by the lvalue used to designate the object.

Is it correct that

- A lvalue has a type, just as  a value (which I believe mean the same as rvalue) does?

  Or, only a rvalue can have a type, while a lvalue doesn't?
- A lvalue has the same type as the value stored in the object designated by the lvalue?

  Or,  a lvalue has a pointer type, because it designates an object which is actually a memory slot with a memory address and size?

  Or, lvalues and rvalues have different types? pointer types are still rvalue types, and pointers are not lvalues themselves, because the C11 standard says

  > if E is a unary expression that is a pointer to an object, *E is an lvalue that designates the object to which E points.

Comment: 1) Yes. It's clearly stated in the passage you quoted. "An lvalue is in expression []with an object type other than void". I would imagine all expressions have a type.

Comment: 2) The quote expression implies an lvalue doesn't always designate an object ("if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated"), so this question can't be answered as is.

Comment: Some types, such as `char`, bitfields, and arrays can only exist as lvalues and not as values, since when evaluated they will be promoted to either an integer type (for the first two), or a pointer type (for the last).

Comment: An lvalue can't have a pointer type, because bitfield lvalues designate objects that you can't create pointers to.

Comment: @supercat: Operands are not always promoted. In each of the operator clauses in C 2018 6.5, it is explicitly stated if the integer promotions or usual arithmetic conversions are performed and is omitted if they are not. The left operand of simple assignment is not promoted or converted. If it is a `char` lvalue, it remains a `char` lvalue (and is not subject to lvalue conversion since 6.3.2.1 2 excepts it). Similarly, an array that is the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` undergoes neither array-to-pointer nor lvalue conversion.

Comment: Re “A lvalue has the same type as the value stored in the object designated by the lvalue?”: Not in general. C 2018 6.2.5 says “The meaning of a value stored in an object or returned by a function is determined by the *type* of the expression used to access it.” You can access an object defined as one type using an lvalue expression of another type. This may or may not have defined behavior, depending on circumstances.

Comment: you [shouldn't use thanks or any kinds of signatures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/230282) in the post

Comment: @phuclv FYI there is some [history on that theme](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389435) (deleted, so 10K users only). See the other answers too.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The left-hand operand of a simple assignment isn't evaluated, so promotions that would occur as a result of evaluation do not occur, but if the assignment expression itself is used as a term within another expression, evaluation of the assignment expression will promote its value (which, at the compiler's convenience, might be evaluated by reading the object to which the value was just stored).

Comment: @supercat: Re “which, at the compiler's convenience, might be evaluated by reading the object”: That would be very unfortunate for programmers assigning values to volatile objects. Fortunately, it is not true. (At the implementation level, the “as if“ rule generally allows it for non-volatile objects, but the discussion here is just about the semantics within the C model, not at the implementation level.)

Comment: @supercat: Re “The left-hand operand of a simple assignment isn't evaluated”: The left operand must be evaluated (because we cannot know what `foo[x+f(y)]` refers to without evaluating it), and the C standard refers to this evaluation (C 2018 6.5.16 3: “… is sequenced after the value computations of the left and right operands”). No lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is performed, but the operand is otherwise evaluated.

Comment: What happens to the left-hand expression as a whole isn't evaluation, but the Standard doesn't define any term to describe it.  Were I in charge of the Standard, I would say that it is "resolved", and that resolving an lvalue that dereferences a pointer would require evaluating that pointer.  Evaluating an address-of expression requires resolving (but not evaluating) its operand.

Comment: @supercat "evaluate" for an lvalue means resolving which memory location it designates. The left hand operand is evaluated, e.g. `*f() = 5;` performs a function call.  In fact 6.3.2.1/1 specifically talks about evaluating an lvalue.

Comment: @M.M: Hmm... I guess the Standard uses the term "lvalue conversion", rather than "evaluate", to describe the action of reading an object's value, though most of the terms where it uses the term "evaluate" would include rvalue conversion without explicitly specifying it.  So I guess what's missing is a verb to describe the concept of evaluating an expression that may or may not be an lvalue, in a fashion that would include lvalue conversion if the expression happens to be an lvalue.

Comment: @supercat that's right about lvalue conversion; and the standard does underspecify when it is performed, and in fact doesn't seem to specify "evaluate" at all .  One of those things where trying to formalize it leads to more problems than trusting the reader to udnerstand, perhaps

Comment: @M.M: I think if the Standard used the term "evaluate" to refer to actions which yield a non-l-value, and "resolve" to refer to actions which process an lvalue for the purpose of identifying the associated storage, most uses of the term "evaluate" could remain as they are, but one could describe many optimizations much more usefully.  For example, if one were to specify that the actions of resolving an object and accessing the associated storage are generally unsequenced with regard to anything that happens between them, that could allow most of the useful optimizations associated with...

Comment: ...the "strict aliasing rule", while supporting most of the useful constructs which that rule would needlessly characterize as UB.  Given `T1 *p1; T2 *p2; p1 = &union1->v1; p2 = &union2->v2; *p1 = v1; *p2 = v2; v3 = *p1;`, such a rule would entitle a compiler to consolidate the accesses to `*p1` because they are unsequenced relative to the assignment to `*p2`, but if the address of `union2->v2` were taken after the assignment to `*p1`, and code re-took the address of `union1->v1` after the assignment to `*p2`, then operations involving the pointers would be sequenced.

Comment: @M.M: Incidentally, given `int i=0,a[10]; int f(void) { return ++i; } int test(void) a[f()] = 4;}` what would be produced by the "evaluation" of the lvalue `a[f()]`?  The Standard would suggest that the result of evaluating an expression using the `[]` operator would be an lvalue, but an lvalue is defined as an expression, and I can't see how any expression would exist during the execution of a program that doesn't appear in the preprocessed source.

Comment: @supercat "expression" is a syntactical construct, `a[f()]` is an expression, evaluating it involves calling `f()` and the result of evaluation is designation of whatever memory location

Answer (score 0):

An lvalue is an expression (specified in the text you quoted already). All expressions have a type. Therefore all lvalues have types.

The standard doesn't have an explicit statement "all expressions have a type"; however in section 6.5 *Expressions* where all possible expression syntax is enumerated, the definition of each expression specifies the type of that expression.

The type of an lvalue might differ from the type of the object designated by the lvalue, e.g. after `int x;` then `*(unsigned int *)&x` is an lvalue of type `unsigned int` designating an object of type `int`.  The strict aliasing rule specifies in which circumstances it is permitted to access an object via an lvalue of a different type to the object.